# c# - Register key events - Shows as virus

Tags: c#, keylogger

Having quite a issue here. What I'm trying to archive is a application which won't be seen as a keylogger. I got this application which i would like to do stuff on key press while you are inside another game. But the way i found my self using was scanned and it shown as a key logger due to global key registration.

Is there any way to avoid this in order to make such application?

Comment: Which antivirus are you using?

Comment: But, it really is a keylogger.

Comment: Hans Passant is right, it is picking it up as a keylogger because it is, it is doing what a keylogger does.

Comment: There (hopefully) is no way to prevent this from the program itself. You (the User) will need to mark the program as an exception in the scanning software.

Comment: Write your own driver to take keyboard presses. It's hard to detect as keylogger from an another software.

Comment: Bali, @LostInLib and Henk Holterman. This was what i was looking for. Thanks. LostInLib, if you write an answer to this question you will get the answer mark and points. As that is a solution to my problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It's illegal if you are working on a harmfull software. If so, I'm suggesting > [that wiki](http://www.wikihow.com/Survive-in-Federal-Prison) <**

*You should search with these terms;*

"What is Ring 0"

"What is Kernel Mode"

"Ring 0 Keylogger"

"Take Key Press Events Sys Driver"
etc.

Kernel mode keyloggers are hard to detect.
But they can be detected too. They are not invisible completly.
Here are the source codes that I found;
[Ring 0 Keylogger](http://forum.sysinternals.com/need-source-code-keylogger-kernel-mode_topic20875.html) and [Keyboard Monitoring](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43144/Keystroke-Monitoring)

Also I'm suggesting [that book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735625301), nice too read and learn win os.

Good luck !

Comment: Thanks. What I'm working on is a jungle timer for the game called league of legends. Which i need to register keypress events for :) Thanks again.